# Passing ViewModel in RedirectToAction causing ViewModel properties to be null

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a requirement, where I need to pass the same instance of a `ViewModel` through to multiple actions in a controller.  I am aware you can do this using `RedirectToAction` like below. The `ViewModel` has a property named `ServiceTimes` (which is a list). This has one item inside it, however when entering my `OnlineBookingStaff` action, the `ServiceTimes` property in here is null. Why is this?

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> OnlineBookingServices(OnlineBookingViewModel viewModel)
{
    try
    {
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(OnlineBookingStaff), viewModel);
    }
}
```

The Action looks like this:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnlineBookingStaff(OnlineBookingViewModel viewModel)
{
    try
    {
        return View(viewModel);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        await ExceptionAsync("Problem displaying Staff, Please try again later.", ex, false, true);
        return View();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share code of `OnlineBookingViewModel`?

Comment: Can these exception handlers ever actually catch and handle an exception?  These seem... superfluous to me.  As for the problem itself, what is the structure of `OnlineBookingViewModel`?  When is the HTTP redirect response from the server and what is the resulting HTTP request from the browser?

Comment: The code you have shown will work fine but only if `OnlineBookingViewModel` contains only simple properties. If the model contains properties which are complex objects or collections, then those properties will be `null` (look at the ugly query string your creating to understand why). But you should not be doing this anyway - you risk exceeding the query string limit and throwing an exception

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`RedirectToAction` sends an HTTP 302 response and causes a client side redirect, which will end up in a GET to the url, losing your model.

You can instead just call it directly:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> OnlineBookingServices(OnlineBookingViewModel viewModel)
{
    return await OnlineBookingStaff(viewModel);
}
```

Comment: One thing worth noting here is that the resulting URL of the page client-side would still be that of `OnlineBookingServices`, not `OnlineBookingStaff`.  This *might* present other problems, or it might not, depending on things outside the scope of the question here.

Comment: This works, thanks.  However as OnlineBookingStaff returns a Task<IActionResult> I had to add an await like this:  return await OnlineBookingStaff(viewModel);

Comment: @DavidBeaumont Thanks - I missed that

Comment: This is not correct. `RedirectToAction()` with generate a query string based on each property of the model. But if the model contains properties which are complex objects or collections it will generate say `.../OnlineBookingServices?someProperty=System.Collections.Generic.List'[someModel]` which cannot be bound to that property.